# Getting the most frequent letter the words in a list of String nodes starts using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have the class:

```
public class WordNode {

    private String _word;
    private WordNode _next;
....
}
```

and the following list:

```
public class TextList {
    private WordNode _head;

    public char mostFrequentStartingLetter(....){}
}
```

In the TextList class I should use a recursive method (mostFrequentStartingLetter) which returns the most frequent letter the words in the list starts with...
I have no idea from where to start even.....

Please help...

Thanks,
Alona

Just so you know i am not cheating:

```
public class TextList {
    private WordNode _head;

    public TextList(String text) {
    String word = "";
    WordNode tmp;

    // After the split that in the array we are going over all the array
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < text.length(); j++) {
            if (text.charAt(j) == ' ') {
                word = text.substring(0, j);
                text = text.substring(j + 1);
                i = 0;
                break;
            } else if (j == text.length() - 1) {
                word = text.substring(0, j + 1);
                text = text.substring(j + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (_head == null) {
            tmp = new WordNode(word, null);
            _head = tmp;
        }
        // if the word starts with a smalles letter then the head, make it
        // the head
        else if (_head.getWord().compareTo(word) > 0) {
            tmp = new WordNode(word, _head);
            _head = tmp;

        } else {
            WordNode current;
            current = _head;
            // go over all the nodes in the list and push the current word
            // to the list in the right order
            while (current.getNext() != null) {
                if (current.getWord().compareTo(word) < 1
                        && current.getNext().getWord().compareTo(word) > 0) {
                    tmp = new WordNode(word, current.getNext());
                    current.setNext(tmp);

                    break;
                }
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            // If the current was the tail, check that the word is bigger
            // and then make it the tail.
            if (current.getNext() == null
                    && current.getWord().compareTo(word) < 1) {
                tmp = new WordNode(word, null);
                current.setNext(tmp);

            }
        }
    }

    }

    public String mostFrequentWord() {

        String frequentWord = _head.getWord();
        WordNode current = _head;
        int count = 0;
        int max = 0;

        while (current.getNext() != null) {

            if (current.getWord().compareTo(current.getNext().getWord()) == 0) {
                count++;
            }

            if (count > max) {
                max = count; frequentWord = current.getWord();
            }

            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return frequentWord;
    }

    public String toString() {

        String s = "";
        WordNode current = _head;
        int count = 1;

        while (current != null) {
            while (current.getNext() != null && current.getWord().equals(current.getNext().getWord())) {

                count++;
                current = current.getNext();
            }

            s += current.getWord() + "\t" + count + "\n";
            count = 1;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return s;
    }

    public char mostFrequentStartingLetter(....){}
}
```

Comment: So, you've got a linked list of words. Do you know how to iterate through them? Try writing some code to print them all out. If you can do that, I'll help you with the rest.

Comment: Yeap... I've almost finished but this one killed me...

Comment: @AlonaGuida Think about how you'd iterate over a linked list recursively.

Comment: for loop to iterate over the words. sorted array, or hashmap, or some other data structure to store the results.what are you having trouble with?

Comment: This is the constructor:

Comment: or while loop might be better if this is a linked list as Vivin stated.

Comment: ohhh... to long just a sec

Comment: This is one more method:
public String mostFrequentWord() {
  String frequentWord = _head.getWord();
  WordNode current = _head;
  int count = 0;
  int max = 0;
  while (current.getNext() != null) {
   if (current.getWord().compareTo(current.getNext().getWord()) == 0) {
    count++;
   }
   if (count > max) {
    max = count;
    frequentWord = current.getWord();
   }
   current = current.getNext();
  }
  return frequentWord;
 }

Comment: This is the printing one:

public String toString() {
  String s = "";
  WordNode current = _head;
  int count = 1;

  while (current != null) {
   while (current.getNext() != null
     && current.getWord().equals(current.getNext().getWord())) {
    count++;
    current = current.getNext();
   }
   s += current.getWord() + "\t" + count + "\n";
   count = 1;
   current = current.getNext();
  }

  return s;
 }

Comment: I have to use recursion on this one...

Comment: I wouldn't stick this much code in the comments... let me put that in the question text for you and you can revert the change if you don't like it.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here :-)
Never asked for help before and this is new for me

Answer (score 2):

Since this is homework, I'll only give you some hints.

There are two things you need to do here.

- Iterate over your linked list recursively.
- Keep track of starting letters.

When you have a recursive function, you need a stopping condition. Think about the stopping condition for your linked list. How do you know when you have reached the end of your linked list? What would the value of `_next` be?

Your method would end up looking something like this:

```
///The pieces in the angle brackets are for you to figure out.
public void determineStartingLetter(WordNode currentNode) {
    if(!<stopping condition>) {
        determineStartingLetter(<next node after currentNode>);
    }
}
```

Now this only traverses the linked list. You also need to keep track of the starting characters you've seen so far. Think about the structure you could use to do that. You want to *map* the character to the *number of times you've seen it*. What data structure would do that for you?

Now where could you maintain such a structure? The easiest solution (but not the most maintainable or elegant) would be a private member of the `TextList` class. But there is a better way. What if you could simply pass this data structure into the recursive method, and then pass into every recursive call?

So then your method would look like this:

```
//As before, the things in angle brackets are for you to figure out.
public <data structure> determineStartingLetter(WordNode currentNode, <data structure>) {
    if(!stopping condition>) {
        <look at starting letter for currentNode>
        <increment the count for this letter in the data structure>
        return determineStartingLetter(<next node after currentNode>, <data structure>);
    }

    return <data structure>
}
```

This should give you enough of a hint to figure out how to do it. In the second part I've actually given you some more hints than I should have :).

Comment: Thank you very much for you quick answer :-)

But with your direction in the end I would have to use a loop that goes over the counts of the letters and then calculate the biggest.
I was prohibited from using loops anywhere in this specific method

Comment: @AlonaGuida If you cannot use loops, then you will need to use a data-structure that will maintain the ordering for you. Take a look at Java's collection classes to see which one can do it for you.

Comment: LOL
probably I will not get the highest score for this, but this is so funny, they will not expect this:


public char mostFrequentStartingLetter() {

  TextList newTextList = new TextList();
  return mostFrequentStartingLetter(_head, newTextList).mostFrequentWord().charAt(0);
 }

Comment: //I know you'll hate me for this, but hey, it works :-)
 public TextList mostFrequentStartingLetter(WordNode current,
   TextList newTextList) {
  if (current != null) {

   newTextList.addToData(current.getWord().substring(0, 1));
   return mostFrequentStartingLetter(current.getNext(), newTextList);
  }

  else{
   newTextList.addToData(" ");
   return newTextList;
  }
 }